# How to set Firebase Database URL (Unity)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to create a login with Facebook with Firebase.
My login function is:

```css
public void FacebookLogin()
    {
        var perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email" };
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            
            string aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId;
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

            Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(aToken);
           
            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                    return;
                }
                
                Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                    newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
            });



        }

       
    }
```

My problem is the warning "Database URL not set in the Firebase config.", followed by a SignInWithCredentialAsync error (System.AggregateException).
How can I change the URL in Firebase config? Where is this Firebase config located?
I'm a newbie in coding, thanks for the support.

I should manage to link all the Id app, Oauth etc correctly( i hope so), I believe the problem is caused by the empty URL for firebase db.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is a [bug](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/946) in the Firebase games SDKs at the moment, which makes it require that a `databaseURL` value is specified in the `google-services.json` and/or `google-services-info.plist` files. Unfortunately that key is not present anymore, unless you actually use the Realtime Database.

The easiest might be to:

1. Create a Realtime Database instance in the Firebase console.
2. Download the updated configuration files and add them to your project again.

---

**Update**: I just spotted that the [issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/946) on Github also mentions a [workaround](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/946#issuecomment-774382746) for the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I deleted the old google-services text file in the assets folder of my Unity project, then downloaded the google-services text file from the Authentication tab of my project anew, and pasted it into the Assets folder of my Unity project. Now everything seems to be fine and I can successfully register new users in my project.