# Firebase failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance in Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, mobile

You want to use the real-time database functionality of Google Firebase.
You have followed the guide page to complete all of them.

I also downloaded the Google-services file.
The Firebase SDK installation is also complete.

I also created a database from the Firebase console.

My code is so simple because I was just testing it.

```
public class FirebaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    DatabaseReference fbRef;
    void Start(){
       fbRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }
}
```

what's wrong with `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;` ??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk8SH.png)

I've redownloaded the google-service.json file and
added
`"firebase_url" : "https://gamename-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"`
this line to `project_info` in google-services.json.

and I added these 2 lines to mainTemplate.gradle (Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle)

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163922/how-to-set-firebase-database-url-unity) question might be able to help you, since the issue lies in the firebase_url not being read properly.

Comment: @Velorexe I checked that question and downloaded config files again but still same. but still thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
fbRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
```

try using

```
const string url = "https://gamename-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/";
fbRef = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(url).RootReference;
```

This directly calls a [function](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/blob/main/database/src/FirebaseDatabase.cs#L134) shown in your screenshot that is currently being passed a null or empty string. If this works the issue is that something about passing the url from the json file is not going through properly (which could result from formatting or building for the wrong build target or any number of things).